# How to extract system uptime from html using regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need to know uptime of the modem. I've examined the html; first the day counter should be extracted and then the timespan. I know there is Html Agility Pack but I want to keep it simple.

This is the html source snippet from the modem:

```
<tr><td><b><span id='SystemUpTime'>System Up Time</span></b></td><td>0 <span id='RgSwInfodays'>days</span> 00h:02m:09s</td></tr>
```

What would be the regex codes to extract day and then time?

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the timestamp looks unique to me so i would use its pattern

**time**

```
[0-9]{2}h:[0-9]{2}m:[0-9]{2}s
```

**day**

if the day is always folloed by  `<span id='RgSwInfodays'>` and has a length 1-3

```
[0-9]{1,3}(?= <span id='RgSwInfodays'>)
```

Comment: <td>0 <span id='RgSwInfodays'> is also unique, what would be the pattern here?

Comment: Thanks, I now hate this place bec. of downvoters who votes in 2 seconds.